# Bash script any reason why it wont write the file

Tags: bash

I am helping debug some code that `exec` the following script is there any reason why its not writing a file to the server? - if that what it does.  All the `$` data and `permissions` are ok:

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

RANGE=$1

ALLOCATION=`echo $RANGE | cut -f1,2,3 -d'.'`


/sbin/ip rule add from $1 lookup $2



echo $ALLOCATION

rm /path/too/file/location/$ALLOCATION

for i in `seq 3 254`

do

echo $ALLOCATION.$i >> /path/too/file/location/$ALLOCATION

done

ETH=`/sbin/ifconfig | grep eth0 | tail -n1 | cut -f2 -d':' | cut -f1 -d' '`
```

Comment: Run the script with `> bash -x ./yourscript.sh` which will give you extra warnings during execution that might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer - Not extra warnings.  It enables `xtrace` mode which prints each command before it runs it.  It allows you to see exactly what the script is doing after variable substitution and the like.

Comment: Yes, that's a more concise description, thanks Llama.

Comment: Thanks @PaulProgrammer however I have run the command via ssh and get `bash: -x: command not found` - Linux cPanel CentOS

Comment: I have run ` > bash ./myScript.sh` and I have got the following: `Error: an inet prefix is expected rather than "lookup". and one that I am glad to see `rm : cannot remove ./myScript.sh: line 20: /file/path Is a directory

Comment: Call the script with an argument. The argument will be used for $1, $RANGE and $ALLOCATION and will be something like an ip-address. The second param will only be used for `/sbin/ip`